# .NET - Line ends in serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

is it possible to set the end-of-line format (\r\n vs \n) for serialization independently of the operating system? So that in WIN and in Linux the result of the command would be the same?

I mean that the result of

`System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, new JsonSerializerOptions {WriteIndented = true});`

or

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);`

would be in both systems:

`{\r\n
    "a": "b"\r\n
..
}`

Thanks a lot.
Tom

Comment: Which really makes me wonder what sort of crazy parser you're working with that the other end that even cares?!

Comment: I just have small tool which serializes some data to json. But sometimes I run the tool in win and sometimes in ubuntu; and I need to compare the results. When line ends differs, the results are never the same even if the content is the same.

Comment: Sounds like you need a better diff tool! My vote goes to BeyondCompare. A naive approach of `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented).Replace("\r\n","\n")` may suffice if this is an infrequently run thing

Answer (score 0):

Nothing built in, but you can serialize to a `MemoryStream` instead of directly to a file, reposition to the beginning of the stream, open a `StreamReader` over it and then manually write line by line (read from the `StreamReader`) to a binary-mode opened file, entering whatever line endings you wish.

If you properly use `Span<>` slices instead of `Substring`, it's actually just as efficient as the original call.